# compare strings with differences and similarities

Tags: php

I use this function to compare strings..

But how to add one more property to the return array with all the similarities in the two strings?

```
function get_decorated_diff($old, $new){
    $from_start = strspn($old ^ $new, "\0");        
    $from_end = strspn(strrev($old) ^ strrev($new), "\0");

    $old_end = strlen($old) - $from_end;
    $new_end = strlen($new) - $from_end;

    $start = substr($new, 0, $from_start);
    $end = substr($new, $new_end);
    $new_diff = substr($new, $from_start, $new_end - $from_start);  
    $old_diff = substr($old, $from_start, $old_end - $from_start);

    $new = "$start<ins style='background-color:#ccffcc'>$new_diff</ins>$end";
    $old = "$start<del style='background-color:#ffcccc'>$old_diff</del>$end";

    return array("old"=>$old, "new"=>$new);
}

$string_old = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
$string_new = "The quick white rabbit jumped over the lazy dog";
$diff = get_decorated_diff($string_old, $string_new);
echo "<table>
    <tr>
        <td>".$diff['old']."</td>
        <td>".$diff['new']."</td>
    </tr>
</table>";
```

Comment: I, for one, don't feel like sharing my morning's first cup of office-coffee with trying to devise what this "comment-free" function does. So, why don't you edit this post to *tell us?* Show example inputs and outputs, and what it produces now. Then, in your own words, what (else) you want it to do. Then, count yourself very lucky if someone proceeds to "write the code for you."

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you're asking to do? I ran the above, and it's pretty neat: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ2HQ.png

Answer (score 1):

From what I get you want a modification to show only similarities:

```
<?php
function get_decorated_diff($old, $new, $get_similarity=false){
    $from_start = strspn($old ^ $new, "\0");        
    $from_end = strspn(strrev($old) ^ strrev($new), "\0");

    $old_end = strlen($old) - $from_end;
    $new_end = strlen($new) - $from_end;

    $start = substr($new, 0, $from_start);
    $end = substr($new, $new_end);
    $new_diff = substr($new, $from_start, $new_end - $from_start);  
    $old_diff = substr($old, $from_start, $old_end - $from_start);

    $new = "$start<ins style='background-color:#ccffcc'>$new_diff</ins>$end";
    $old = "$start<del style='background-color:#ffcccc'>$old_diff</del>$end";
    if($get_similarity)
    $get_similarity = "<ins style='background-color:#ccffcc'>$start $end</ins>"; 
    return array("old"=>$old, "new"=>$new, "similarity"=>$get_similarity);
}

$string_old = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
$string_new = "The quick white rabbit jumped over the lazy dog";
$diff = get_decorated_diff($string_old, $string_new, true);
echo "<table border=1>
    <tr align=center>
        <td>old</td>
        <td>new</td>
        <td>similarity</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>".$diff['old']."</td>
        <td>".$diff['new']."</td>
        <td>".$diff['similarity']."</td>
    </tr>
</table>";

?>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, this function is really useful. Sadly, there are some problems when the end of the news string have the same characters or at the same index than the old string. For example, comparing "RET" with "RETRET" result in "RET<del style='background-color:#ffcccc'></del>RET". Any advices to correct that ?

Comment: Hi, I'll take a look to that. If you found this snippet useful. Please upvote :)  @FLX